# Reloading div only if database has new records

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below code which is reloading new records if inserted.
On page load it works fine But after reloading div when get new data, it is keep reloading again and again and also not including a file which is included in **order_new_orders.php**.

I want only reload the div if new record inserted and then keep close.

**order_new_orders.php**

```
**EXAMPLE:**

$sqla   = "select order_id from orders where status = 0
and store_id = '".$_SESSION['ses_user_idx']."'";
$sqlb   = $dba2->query($sqla);
while ($sqlc    = $sqlb->fetch_assoc()){

include ('inc/afile.php');

echo $sqlc['name'];

}
```

**Code:**

```
var currentNewOrders = "";
function auto_loadNewOrders(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'order_new_orders.php',
    success: function(data){
       if(currentNewOrders !== data) {
           $("#newOrderRefresh").html(data);
           currentNewOrders = data;
       }
    }
  });
}
auto_loadNewOrders();
setInterval(auto_loadNewOrders,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

*PHP*

order_new_orders.php

```
<?php

//Dummy Data
$datas = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dummy Name1', 'age' => 25),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Dummy Name2', 'age' => 28),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Dummy Name2', 'age' => 28),
);

if (isset($_GET['checkNew']) && isset($_GET['lastDataID'])) {
    if (count($datas) > $_GET['lastDataID']) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 'No new Data';
    }
    exit;
}

//Data Output structure 
$htm = "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        ";

foreach ($datas as $row) {
    $htm.="<tr class='data-row' data-row-id='$row[id]'>
            <td>$row[name]</td>
            <td>$row[age]</td>
          </tr>";
}
$htm.="</table>";
echo $htm;
exit;
```

*HTML & jQuery*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="newOrderRefresh"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        auto_loadNewOrders();
        setInterval(checkForNew, 1000);
    });

    function auto_loadNewOrders() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'order_new_orders.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#newOrderRefresh").html(data);
            }
        });

    }

    function checkForNew() {
        var lastData = $('.data-row').last().attr('data-row-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'order_new_orders.php?checkNew&lastDataID=' + lastData,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    auto_loadNewOrders();
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried but its not refreshing every second or whatever. please write any query not the dummy data

Comment: @usman610 if you want query than please give me your `database table` structure

Comment: you can make any query so i will adjust the query as per my need

Comment: You just pay attention in this  code `<tr class='data-row' data-row-id='$row[id]'>` .  every data single Row must contains that's row ID

Comment: im adding this `$sqlx4 = "select i from orders_placed where status = 0 and store_id = '".$_SESSION['ses_user_idx']."'";
$sqlx5  = $dba2->query($sqlx4);
while ($sql6  = $sqlx5->fetch_array()){
$datas []= $sql6;
}` it is showing records but it is not updating.

Comment: what is the table's primary key field name ?

Comment: `id` is the primary key

Comment: it is reloading the div again and again after x seconds.